# AJAX - After success clean input value and set dropdown to selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with a dropdown list and a `input` with `type="text"`.

I'm trying to filter the results of my table via AJAX when I select an option in my dropdown list.

It should clean the value of the input when the option is selected (after the success).

It's working fine.

The problem is that I need it to for my input. It should send the value of the input to AJAX and then filter the results when I submit the form.

I can't put it to work after the suceess. It sets the dropdown list to "selected". I don't know why.

HTML code:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("a","b")" id="filter-date" onsubmit="javascript:return false">   
    <label for="from" class="label-datepicker">from:</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" class="dateinput">
    <label for="to" class="label-datepicker">to:</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" class="dateinput">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-date">
        OK
    </button>
</form>



<select name="Assunto" id="select-a">
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>             
        <option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$("#select-a").change(function () {
        var selected = $("#select-a").val();
        var Keyword = { data: $("#select-a").val() };
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: '@(Url.Action("bo", "b"))',
            data: { Keyword: selected },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".dateinput").val('');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

$("#filter-date").submit(function () {
        var from = $("#from").val();
        var to = $("#to").val();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: '@(Url.Action("update", "b"))',
            data: { From: from, To: to },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#bodylist").html(data);
                $("#select-a").val(selected);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: the variable `selected` is not in the scope of submit function. you are setting that in the success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

As @Anto rightly said

```
var selected = $("#select-a").val();
```

scope of this above statement should be in form-submit also

```
$("#select-a option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
$("#select-a option[value=" + selected+ "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: It definitely shouldn't be dumped into the global scope. You just need to add the line to get the value locally again.

Comment: Don't forget to clear possible other selected options first due to "$("#select-a option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#filter-date").submit(function () {
        var from = $("#from").val();
        var to = $("#to").val();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: '@(Url.Action("update", "b"))',
            data: { From: from, To: to },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#bodylist").html(data);
               // $("#select-a").val(selected); //should remove this line because we use ajax, the page is not refreshed, not need to restore the state.
                 //or $("#select-a").val(""); if you need to reset
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false; //return false at the end to prevent form submitting
    });
```

And remove `onsubmit="javascript:return false"`. And should not use `-` in id attribute.

Comment: @user2232273: I guess it could be problem of `-` in your id

Comment: @user2232273: I don't know why you want to call `$("#select-a").val(selected);`. Can you remove it?

Comment: @user2232273: I guess you want to restore the state when calling `$("#select-a").val(selected);`. Is that right? If so, we don't need that line because we're using ajax, the page is not refreshed.

Comment: @user2232273: If you need to reset the select. Just use `$("#select-a").val("");`

Answer (score 0):

Just make selected global:

```
 (function(){
     var selected;

     $("#select-a").change(function () {
         selected = $("#select-a").val();
         // rest of your script


 })(); // close the wrapper
```

EDIT: Wrapping it up in a self-executing anonymous function will keep the global namespace clean (thanks to @jameslafferty).

Comment: Which should be avoided to keep the global namespace clean – especially when using variables that are likely to be used again by other scripts :/ Proper handling of a local variable space is important!

Comment: You are right and it has to be kept in mind. I'm just giving a simple way to do it.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a self invoking anonymous function and it becomes a non issue. The var isn't global, and can be accessed by everything that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution.. and its solved now.

its more easier if i thought.

the ajax call on .submit doesn´t allow me to do something after success like what i need..

this i don´t know it.

what i have done is to set the value of the option from my dropdownlist to selected before the ajax section.

and the magic is done..

its working now.

this is my new code:

```
$("#filter-date").submit(function () {
        var from = $("#from").val();
        var to = $("#to").val();

    $('#select-a').val('selected');

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: '@(Url.Action("update", "b"))',
            data: { From: from, To: to },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#bodylist").html(data);
                $("#select-a").val(selected);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: you should know the difference between `'selected'` and `selected`. Try replacing `$('#select-a').val(selected);` with `$('#select-a').val('selected');` in your success function.

Comment: the problem is not that it's not working inside the success function. Just because you do it wrong inside the success function.

Comment: @Khanh: i have tested with the same sintaxe in the success section, but still not working..
my answer is the only way in this moment to put this to work but thank you very much for your help
and this conversation about my problem.. i really preciated it.. 
with all the guys i found a alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try use jQuery function `.data(name, value)` to store `selected` value like this:

```
$('#select-a').data('selectedValue', $('#select-a').val());
```

Then in submit handler get it:

```
var selected = $('#select-a').data('selectedValue');
```

And use @Nitin's code to set selected option:

```
$("#select-a option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
$("#select-a option[value=" + selected+ "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```